# Libgdx: Translate 3D Object from one camera to another one

Tags: android, math, 3d, camera, libgdx

I have a 3D Libgdx game with one Perspective Camera looking into the scene which has a fixed position, but flexible direction and up vectors. Then there is another Perspective Camera which renders "static elements" on top. 
One of these static elements is a bow and the arrow.

When the player now shoots, I need to "translate" the arrow so that it is no longer rendered by the second "static" perspective camera, but by the scene view camera as the arrow needs to fly towards where the camera is looking at.

However I don't know how to translate the arrow from its old position, rotation vectors etc. to the ones that it needs to create a seamless "transfer". How would this be done ?

This is how the arrow is created:

```
model = loader.loadModel(Gdx.files.internal("data/arrow.obj"));
arrowModel = new ModelInstance(model);
staticCamera = new PerspectiveCamera(67.0f, 2.0f * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), 2.0f);
 staticCamera.far = 100.0f;
 staticCamera.near = 0.1f;
 staticCamera.position.set(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
 staticCamera.up.set(0f, 1f, 0f);
 staticCamera.lookAt(0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
```

And here is how I render it with the static camera:

```
modelBatch.begin(staticCamera);
modelBatch.render(arrowModel, environment);
modelBatch.end();
```

The dynamic "world" camera changes its direction and up vector depending how the user is holding is phone:

```
Gdx.input.getRotationMatrix(mat4.val);
upVector.push(mat4.val[Matrix4.M11], mat4.val[Matrix4.M12], mat4.val[Matrix4.M10]);
dirVector.push(-mat4.val[Matrix4.M21], -mat4.val[Matrix4.M22], -mat4.val[Matrix4.M20]);

 float[] ups = upVector.getValue();
 float[] dirs = dirVector.getValue();
 camera.up.set(ups[0], ups[1], ups[2]);
 camera.direction.set(dirs[0], dirs[1], dirs[2]);
```

So I am now wondering how the transformation for the arrow has to look like, so that from a visual perspective it is at the same place when I switch from rendering it using the staticCamera to the camera object (world view camera)

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots and codes pls. Also look at  unproject and  getPickRay methods of camera.

Comment: I have added the code now. Unproject and getPickRay I think is for getting the 2D screen coordinates from a 3D world object. However I need to know its 3D world coordinates / transformation matrix based on its 3D UI matrix and the world camera.

Comment: Try: `modelInstance.transform.mul(camFrom.combined).mul(camTo.invProjectionView);`. But it really sounds like you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Just use one camera instead of making things complicated by using two camera's. Also, don't use a `near` value below `1f`.

Comment: Honestly I tried using a single camera first but could not figure out how to keep the bow and arrow visible in always the same visual position regardless of where the camera is looking at...

Comment: @Xoppa I tried your proposal, it looks promising, but there are two things still wrong: 1. It does not seem to take the "world camera"'s up-vector into consideration. The arrow is visible when holding the phone in horizontal position and also in almost the right position, but its invisible when I hold it vertically (no idea what's wrong here) and 2. the arrow's position is shifted by 1f in Y-Axis (which I can of course solve by myself :) )

Comment: If you have a problem using one camera then you're better of to solve that instead of hacking around it and solve the problem you experience while hacking around it.

Comment: You're right, however using a second camera has another advantage: If the player is jittering around, only the targets will also jitter around (as I am using the phone's sensors) but as the bow is rendered using the static camera it will stay in a constant position. Thus I would like to stay with the second one. And your proposal anyway is working with the exception of the up-vector. Any idea how to get that into the calculation ?

Comment: Perhaps you are manually modifying the `up` or `direction` vector without calling `normalizeUp`? Otherwise show your MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.